# How to check if I gave correct nodejs permissions

Tags: permissions, nodejs

I have a problem installing phonegap. The problem seems to be a problem regarding giving the correct permissions for nodejs. How can I check to see if I have given the correct permission for nodejs and if not how can I give the correct permissions?

Comment: If you could share the error stack that says about the "Problem" maybe we could participate a bit more.

Comment: @ArchNoob it doesn't say it in the error that the issue is due to permissions but I contacted the person in charge of the software I was installing (Phonegap. It wouldn't update) and he told me the problem was due to permissions. Could you please provide a link indicating where I could find the information to fix this problem please. Thank you for acknowledging my question.

Comment: I haven't installed `phonegap` myself. But, maybe you could share the command you are using to install `phonegap` and the error it gives (whatever it says) so we can have a clue on what's happening to give better suggestions.

Comment: I just found this https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/fixing-npm-permissions hope it helps.